# What is the most efficient way to heat air?

Tags: electrical-engineering, airflow, aerodynamics, air

I'm currently playing with a school project.

My goal here is to heat a stream of air to a significant temperature so I can demonstrate air expansion.

I have a cylinder, with a few turbines, turning in opposite directions, into another cylinder in the shape of a nozzle. My goal here would be to use the second cylinder, to place a heating device. As air would compress, it would suddenly expand with heat.

Not an over engineered machine, just something that does the trick.

So beside security, my question is what is the most efficient way to heat air through a cylinder? What type of material should i use to both conduct/insulate?

One additional question would be: Does an OverPowered Iow Wind Coil would do?

Feel free to leave some of your knowledge or experiences on this matter, I'm collecting data as we speak, and some clear minds already geared on the subject are always welcome to leave their input.

Have a great day, and bless ya

Comment: It will heavily depend on the amount (flow rate) of air to be heated. Pictures/sketches with dimensions of what you have would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Best demonstration I ever saw was using an old metal motor car oil can.

The physics teacher put an inch or so of water in it and brought it to the boil over a bunsen burner.

Once boiling it was removed from the heat an the lid screwed on tightly. The cooling vapour inside and the air pressure crushed the can over relatively short time.

Once crushed, it was put back on the heat and the increasing temperature caused the vapour to expand and re-inflate the can until it looked almost as original.

**I suggest you do not do this** as oil cans are now plastic and the Health and Safety Police will be all over you - this was in the 1970’s so a long time ago now. Really made us get the idea of atmospheric pressure etc.

Comment: Won't be offering anything else then, even if I may have some other suggestions.